# How do you instrument or Monitor a RabbitMQ Server in a windows environment?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm in a windows environment and installing RabbitMQ on Server 2012. How can I tie SCOM or other monitoring tools to verify that Rabbit is up, running, and healthy.  Do people just monitor the health of their application and not worry about the Rabbit application. Do they have something monitoring the log files and otherwise just use OOTB windows statistics.

Thanks